# xna how to setup controls in game

Tags: menu, xna, key, controls, installation

I want to be able to go to options menu in the game I am developing and set up my controls.
It is a simple game of pong (for now) and the controls for each player are just up and down.

This is how I want the process to look like: I click SETUP CONTROLS, game displays the name of the control I am supposed to change and it waits, I click the button on keyboard that i want it to be changed to, game reads it and displays the next control I am supposed to change and so on until i change all controls.

I have found a way how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933025/xna-controls-settings) and my code now looks basicly like this:

```
if (optionsBList.IsButtonClicked("SETUP CONTROLS")) //when i click the 
                                                    //SETUP CONTROLS button
                                                    //in the options menu
{
    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState =  new KeyboardState();
    waitingForKey = true;
    while (waitingForKey)
    {
        if(currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys().Count() > 0)
        {
            player1.upkey = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()[0];
            //the path for the key isn't player1.upkey, but lets say it is.
            waitingForKey = false;
         }
    }
 }
```

In this short code my goal is to change just one key. If I can make it change 1 key, changing more wont be a problem.

The problem is, I don't see why does my game stop responding when i click the SETUP CONTROLS button. I don't see an infinite loop here nor a memory leak.
Why is my game crashing and is there a better way to load controls in options menu?

Comment: `while(waitingForKey)` is your infinite loop. That loop blocks the game thread, so no further input is recognized. Changing the `while` to `if` should work, as long as this code is executed on every update.

Answer (score 0):

If you saw the answer from the link you placed in your question, you would have noticed that he actually deleted the `while` loop and he made it an `if` statement.

Like *Nico Schertler* said : "while(waitingForKey) is your infinite loop. That loop blocks the game thread, so no further input is recognized."

Link to the answer from your link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935732/3239917

```
if (optionsBList.IsButtonClicked("SETUP CONTROLS")) //when i click the 
                                                    //SETUP CONTROLS button
                                                    //in the options menu
{
    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState =  new KeyboardState();
    waitingForKey = true;
    if (waitingForKey )
    {
        if(currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys().Count() > 0)
        {
            player1.upkey = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()[0];
            //the path for the key isn't player1.upkey, but lets say it is.
            waitingForKey = false;
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, now it doesn't crash but it's not working eather. I did not mention that this peace of code is constantly updated, so sorry about that.